# Dynamic Programming - Finding Maximum Profit

Tags: matrix, dynamic-programming

[image]

[image]

I'm new to dynamic programming. So, I'm suppose to find the max profit. I don't think what I'm doing is correct. I don't understand what the k conversions is for. In the given example there are given 3 currencies, so therefore there are 3 conversion. Can someone please give me more ideas about how to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

First, let's think about how many currency transactions there are.  If you have three currencies (let's call them pounds, francs, and marks) you have six possible *types* of currency transactions:  Pounds to marks, marks to pounds, pounds to francs, francs to pounds, francs to marks, and marks to francs.

But in terms of your problem, when they say you have k currency transactions, what they mean is that you are allowed to start with some currency and make a sequence of k currency transactions.  Your job is to figure out which k transactions will result in the most profit. So for instance, if you have three currencies, but k=1 and you're told to start with pounds, your task is easy:  Decide whether pounds to francs is better, or pounds to marks is better.  If k=2, you have more choices, etc.

It might be helpful to think of this as a weighted directed graph, where the currencies are nodes, and the arcs are weighted by the exchange rates.  Then you can think of the problems in terms of finding the most profitable path through the graph, of length k, starting at node i.

Thinking about it that way will also show you the problem in your expression, which should look like the path along a graph, not what you have.  You might also think about using some properties of logarithms, to turn this from a problem about multiplication into a problem about addition.

And finally, dynamic programming on graph structures usually involves building a solution of length n+1 out of a solution of length n, so you should probably start by thinking about the smallest possible problem, and how it relates to the second smallest problem, etc.

Comment: what is the most profitable solution the longest path in the graph or the shortest path?